# rspec returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to use rspec on my rails application

I run "spec path/to/spec/spec.rb" and it appears to do nothing and returns nothing.  I receive no error

Rails Version 2.3.4
Ruby 1.8.7
Rspec 1.3.0
rspec-rails 1.3.2

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

I'm still getting nothing when running "spec spec/models/fee_spec.rb" or any other *_spec.rb
It works fine for my co-worker on his mac
Here is the file fee_spec.rb

*File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/../spec_helper'

describe Fee do

it "should be valid" do

```
Fee.new.should be_valid
```

end

end*

Comment: Can you try `spec -b path/to/spec/spec.rb` for full backtrace?

Comment: I gave that a try.  It is still just returning without doing anything.

Comment: post the contents of `spec.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer.
There was a problem with test-unit gem that I installed.  I had version 2.0.7 which caused the issue. Downgrading this to test-unit 1.2.3 fixed the issue.